# I have a hardware theory as to why computers crash?

Tags: integrated-circuit

I have an idea as to why a computer might crash for no reason at all.
As you know in a computer information is represented as on or off.
On simply means high voltage and off means low voltage.Now lets say low voltage is between 0 and 1.2V, high voltage is between 3.8v and 5v.Lets say there is a brown out or black out that has occured on the power lines for one millisecond so about one or more bits of information that represnted 1 meaning "high votage"  was transmitted as 2.9v intead of the expected say........4v.That would definitely cause the computer to crash because inside a computer there is a digital logic that is desined to convert analog voltages into simple approximations,  the "0v-1.2v " and the "3.8v-5v" 
If a current transmitted is inbetween  those values like the "2.9v" I suggested there above.
Technically it would be in a "metastable" state.But as we all know the computer knows only two things:on or off, you cant be neither.So the computer would crash because it would have received a result that does not qualify to be a 1 or a 0.I am guessing this happens a lot as we have seen our computer crashing for no reason whatsoever.
Maybe there was a brownout that occured in a millisecond.

This question has a lot to do with circuitry and electrical engineering, so I posted it here since you guys would be the most qualified people.

Is this theory plausible?

(I also happen to be in the 11th grade so dont use too complicated words)

what I meant was :" could this  be a reason for why computers crash?" I'm not trying to say that it is the "only" reason.I hope its now clear Eugene sh

Comment: There is no need in theories. Every "crash" has a good reason, which is perfectly determinable.

Comment: Just thinking about the massive amounts of RAM in a computer and background radiation flipping some bits makes me wonder how on earth we are able to get so little crashes.

Comment: hashing and error checking go a long way to detecting "bad" bytes before they cause damage. but in theory it is possible.

Comment: The voltages fed to the CPU are very, very well regulated. I doubt that millisecond-long brown-outs could occur routinely in a PC. In an Arduino, maybe, but that would trigger a reset (precisely to avoid undetected computation errors). Most 'random' crashes are caused by software and they only appear to be random because there are so many things going on at once on the software side, that the exact same situation almost never occurs twice.

Comment: Logic voltage levels are still a 1 or a 0, if a low voltage condition occurs and the logic level is ambiguous, it will still choose a 1 or a 0. However, you're correct that this may be incorrect and could cause a crash, but most things are transmitted with a form of 'error correction code' (ECC) that transmits that 1 bit (0 or a 1) in multiple bits, which can be used to detect and possibly fix this error, thus preventing a crash.

Comment: _why ... for no reason at all_.  Isn't that an oxymoron?  If there is no reason at all, then how can you talk about "why?"  The "why" _is_ the reason.

Comment: This is exactly what pull-up/pull-down resistors are for -- To prevent this "unknown", or "floating" state. There are literally millions of possible reasons for computers crashing, and what you describe is nothing new

Answer (score 7):

What you describe is a failure due to a too low power supply voltage. This is a well-known cause of crashes, which has prompted manufacturers to take action. One action is inherent in the power supply: it has capacitors that will provide the power to survive short power dip. The nature of a modern switch-mode power supply makes it very resilient againt a brown out: most PSUs can function with an input voltage far below the nominal 110 or 230 V. Other measures are the computer sensing a power failure before it affects it working, and taking appropriate action in software. Small micro-controllers often has a brown-out-rest circuit that halts the chip on a brownout and resets it when power is available again.

But for most crashes in consumer situations my gut feeling is that marginal electronic designs and not-exactly bug free software are more likely causes.

Comment: is right about the PSU and in fact the capacitors/inductors on the motherboard would also have a similar effect. When the electrolytic capacitors on a motherboard fail (bulge) you can get very weird behaviour indeed. eg software will not install or particular applications will not run etc So your gut feeling about how critical a reliable power supply is, is spot on. As an aside another common cause of crashes is by poorly written apps not releasing memory and simply using it all or apps writing over memory in use by another app. But don't stop pondering the mysteries of electronics!

Answer (score 2):

Your theory is plausible. Brown-out voltage conditions can be a cause of these problems; but as Wouter pointed out, many computer power supplies can handle both under-voltage (brown-out) and over-voltage (spike, surge) conditions.

Unfortunately, most situations are more complicated than the one you provided. Your statement,

> But as we all know the computer knows only two things:on or off, you cant be neither.So the computer would crash because it would have received a result that does not qualify to be a 1 or a 0.

isn't quite correct. In your example, the digital logic thresholds you stated (0V-1.2V for low, 3.8V-5V for high) are often provided by manufacturers as guaranteed stable regions. Most digital logic circuits will still interpret signals in-between those stable regions (i.e. 1.2V-3.8V). They will still get a value of high or low. But in these regions, there is no guarantee whether it will be high or low. So a signal at 1.7V **could be** read as high by a chip, even though humans would probably interpret it as a low signal.

It's entirely possible that such conditions could cause a computer to crash. But as technology has advanced, most chips, circuits, and low-level "programs" have become tolerant of these types of faults. Although most computers can handle these conditions, there are also plenty of circuits and systems that can't!

A somewhat related problem has started to gain a lot of attention in relation to computer memory and storage errors, which [error correcting codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECC_memory#Problem_background) attempt to reduce.